# How to enable a Toolbar in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, material-design

I have a simple Xamarin Project with XAML and I would like to use a Material Design, it seems to be enable by default but the toolbar doesn't show along with the MainPage. Or do I need to add a toobar by the xaml?

MainPage.xaml :

```
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Material"
             x:Class="Material.MainPage"> 
  <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin Forms!"
           VerticalOptions="Center"
           HorizontalOptions="Center" />
  <ToolbarItem Name="Test" /> 
</ContentPage>
```

style.xml :

```
 <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
  </style>
  <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
  </style>
```

Toobar.axml :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Tabbar.axml

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
app:tabGravity="fill"
app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

MainActivity.cs :

```
[Activity(Label = "Material", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
}
```

I was following [This](https://blog.xamarin.com/material-design-for-your-xamarin-forms-android-apps/) tutorial. Thanks!

So far I just got this... 
[image]

Comment: As the tutorial that i I mentioned here, Actionbar is gone, now it is AppCompat v7, he did at the tutorial and create the toolbar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should wrap your `ContentPage` in a `NavigationPage` in your `App.(xaml).cs`.

So when defining your `MainPage` inside your `App.(xaml).cs` do it this way:

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
}
```

When you are navigating further, you would not have to wrap the `ContentPage` in a `NavigationPage` each time, as navigation is relative.